# How can i detect if the angular-translate file was loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I am trying to use one-time-binding in my angular application to improve the performance. So I want to use the angular-translate of the next way:

```js
//This code does not work.
function myCtrl($translate){
    $scope.DESCRIPTION = $translate.instant('DESCRIPTION');
}


//I should use a timeout of next way:
//This code does work.
function myCtrl($translate){

   setTimeout(function(){
     $scope.DESCRIPTION = $translate.instant('DESCRIPTION');
   }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<p> {{::DESCRIPTION}} </p>
```

How can i detect when the language json file is loaded?
I does not want to use setTimeouts.

I hope you understand me

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this solution:

```js
function loadTexts(scope, ids) {

  $translate.onReady(function() {

    var size = ids.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      var id = ids[i];
      scope[id] = $translate.instant(id);
    }

  });
};


function myCtrl($scope){
  loadTexts($scope, ['DESCRIPTION', 'HEADER_TEXT']);
}
```

```html
<p> {{::HEADER_TEXT}} </p>
<p> {{::DESCRIPTION}} </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet comes from the [docs](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/03_using-translate-service)

```
app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$translate', function ($scope, $translate) {
  $translate('HEADLINE').then(function (headline) {
    $scope.headline = headline;
  });
  $translate('PARAGRAPH').then(function (paragraph) {
    $scope.paragraph = paragraph;
  });
  $translate('NAMESPACE.PARAGRAPH').then(function (anotherOne) {
    $scope.namespaced_paragraph = anotherOne;
  });
}]);
```

In your case, this should do it.

```
function myCtrl($scope, $translate){
    $translate('DESCRIPTION').then(function (description) {
         $scope.DESCRIPTION = description;
    });
}
```

Although, imo the easiest way to use Angular-Translate, is by using the filter like this. ([docs](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/04_using-translate-filter))

```
<p>{{'DESCRIPTION' | translate}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to translate a string in your controller, instead of injecting the service, you should inject the filter directly...

In angular 1.+ you can inject a filter using the `Filter suffix`.

```
function MyCtrl(translateFilter) { console.log(translateFilter('mystring')); }
```

This should give you security that all filter dependencies are loaded.